# 'bool' object is not iterable for a function

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the index of the element 'True' in a function, but it keeps saying 'bool' object is not iterable for 'num in find'. The output I was hoping to get was [2,3,4,6,7] but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
list = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]


def find (state):
    data2 = []
    for num in state:
        if [num] == True:
            list2.append(num)
            return data2
            
for k in range(len(list)):
    final = find (list[k])
    print(final)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enumerate is your friend:

```
data = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
print([index for index, el in enumerate(data) if el])
```

prints `[2, 3, 4, 6, 7]`

Also `list` is a keyword and should not be used.

Comment: @ midin How would I input this inside a function?

Comment: You can just do the list comprehension result saved in a variable and return it
So
```x = [index for index, el in enumerate(data) if el]```
```return x```

Comment: @MohamedAly8 that works but now my output keeps repeating itself?

Comment: When you call the function is it in a loop of some sort?